# Using multiple delimiters with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to parse a text file to get the current version of software. The string I'm looking for looks similar to this:

"Foo bar (Version: 10.2)gak"

Awk supports using multiple delimiters which I thought would be a good readable solution. For some reason this doesn't work:

```
$ echo "Foo bar (Version: 10.2)gak" | awk -F')| ' '/Version/ {print $4}'
10.2)gak
```

Does anyone happen to know what the correct syntax would be for this? Based on what I see in the man page this should work. Must be missing something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually weird because in my shell (which is git-bash for windows), your command works properly:

[image: Command Result]

Maybe you have an old version of awk that is behaving differently. My version of awk is : `GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)`

anubhava's answer also gives the same result, so, if it does not work either, I would try to have a look at the version of awk you are using.

Comment: You're spot on. This definitely looks like an awk version issue. I'll need to do some digging to see what the differences are.

Comment: @anubhava I don't think there's anything wrong with that regexp - what do you think the problem is? FWIW I suspect the OP is using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris).

Comment: It is because an unescaped `)` is not a valid regex.

Comment: A `)` only needs to be escaped when matched with a preceding `(`, just like `]` with `[`.

Comment: `awk` on OSX complains with this as: `awk: illegal primary in regular expression )|  at |`

Comment: Also `echo "Foo bar (Version: 10.2)gak" | grep -oP ')| ' returns this error:
`grep: unmatched parentheses`

Comment: Then OSX awk is simply not POSIX compliant (IIRC it's non-POSIX in other ways too) and `-P` is stated in the grep man page as being "highly experimental` so all bets are off wrt what that might do plus even if it does "work" it's using Perl regexps, not EREs as used by awk like we're discussing. There's just no common sense reason to have to escape a `)` that isn't terminating a preceding `(`. Does OSX also require a standalone `]` to be escaped?

Comment: Exactly for that reason I wrote `')| '` is unsafe since it depends upon what awk is in use. `'[(): ]+'` should work with all POSIX, BSD (osx) and gnu awk versions.

Comment: OSX awk works fine as: `echo "Foo bar (Version: 10.2)gak" | /usr/bin/awk -F '\\)| ' '/Version/ {print $4}'`

Comment: `is unsafe since it depends upon what awk is in use` would be fine to state along with a "why", it was the `is a wrong regex and gnu awk just masks this error ` statement that caught my attention as it's not wrong and gawk isn't masking anything, it's just using it in a POSIXly correct way. Not sure how much we should cater to non-POSIX awks of course but it's reasonable to point out the differences when they occur.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a character class of delimiters as:

```
echo "Foo bar (Version: 10.2)gak" | /usr/bin/awk -F '[(): ]+' '/Version/{print $4}'
10.2
```

Regex `[(): ]+` is using a character class that sets delimiters as one or more of `(` or `)` or `:` or space characters.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: `[(): ]` is not a character class, it's a bracket expression `[...]` containing a character list `(): `. A character class would, for example, be `[:alpha:]` which you could also use within a bracket expression as `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: [As per my understanding POSIX bracket expression is almost same as a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) also see this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: I just finished reading the character class discussion at regular-expressions.info and it looks like the regexp language they are describing is simply something other than POSIX and so the `[...]` construct that they refer to as a `character class` is functionally the same as what POSIX refers to as a `bracket expression` while the regexp language described at RE.info simply does not have an equivalent for POSIX character classes (e.g. `[:alpha:]`) but they DO have syntax for saying "except" (e.g. `[a-z-[aeiou]]` = `lower case except vowels`) and other non-POSIX constructs.

Comment: Whatever the application is for those regexps, it's not awk or any other UNIX tool I know of and so IMHO we should not use their terminology in the context of UNIX tools and stick to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) terminology instead.